# Is it possible to return a single result set of the UNION of a (variable) number of selects in a MySQL stored procedure without using EXECUTE?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, union

I'm creating a stored procedure in MySQL that, given a domain name, should make one select query for each "level" in the domain name (all to the same table, returning the same fields), and return the UNION of the results of these queries as a single result set.

Since the queries are performed in a loop (i.e. the number of queries depends on the number of levels in the domain name provided as a parameter to the stored procedure), I cannot just use a static SQL statement containing multiple selects with UNION between them.

Rather, I need to make the select queries iteratively, or alternatively build a concatenated SQL query string in this loop, and EXECUTE this after the loop.

The latter solution (concatenated SQL statement) sounds both "ugly" and "dangerous" (security wise) to me, and I'd therefore much rather do it "natively" somehow, but I'm not sure if this is possible?

I've figured as much that I could use temp tables to store the results of the query in each loop iteration, but then I instead get stuck on how to finally UNION the contents of all these temp tables (remember: there will be a variant number of these temp tables for each call to my stored procedure) without using EXECUTE in the end anyway? (this would of course be a much less ugly and risky use of EXECUTE than building the entire multi-UNION SQL statement from scratch and executing this, but I'm still curious if EXECUTE should really be needed at all to accomplish this?)

Does anyone have any kind of elegant/recommended solution for this use case (which I would think must be at least a not too uncommon one after all?)?

Here is my function so far, just in case someone is curious or thinks it gives them better insight into my problem:

```
CREATE lookup_domain(IN lookup_name VARCHAR(4096))
BEGIN
    DECLARE noof_levels int(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE remaining_levels varchar(4096) DEFAULT '';
    SET noof_levels = ROUND((LENGTH(lookup_name)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lookup_name, ".", ""))) / LENGTH("."));
    SET remaining_levels = lookup_name;
    WHILE noof_levels >= 1 DO
        SET  noof_levels = noof_levels - 1; 
        #This will simply print the current domain level
        #but in reality it will look up properties of it in a table,
        #like: SELECT name, prop1, prop2, prop3 FROM domains WHERE name = ?
        #and it's these results that I want to UNION into a single result set
        SELECT remaining_levels AS 'debug_res';
        SET remaining_levels = SUBSTRING(remaining_levels,LOCATE('.', remaining_levels)+1);
    END WHILE;
END
```

So, the desired (single) result set of a call to this function with the parameter "some.test.domain.com" should be something like:

```
------------------------------------------------
| name                 | prop1 | prop2 | prop3 |
------------------------------------------------
| some.test.domain.com | ...   | ...   | ...   |
| test.domain.com      | ...   | ...   | ...   |
| domain.com           | ...   | ...   | ...   |
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning of the procedure, create a temporary table with the definitions for the output columns you'll be returning.  The temporary table namespace is scoped to the session (database connection) so there is no possibility of two concurrent run of the procedure causing a collision on that name.

```
-- in case it is there from a previous run if the proc in the same session
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_lookup;
-- define the columns for the output
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_lookup (name ...
-- the above statements go before this next line
SET noof_levels = ...
```

Then, in the loop, change `SELECT` to `INSERT ... SELECT`, writing the results to the temp table, instead of sending immediately to the client.

```
INSERT INTO tmp_lookup SELECT name...
```

After `END WHILE;`, return all the collected rows to the caller:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp_lookup;
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I was hoping there was a way to "append" the iterative results directly into a temp table like this!